# A term for 'thinking something evil is good'?

Tags: single-word-requests

So if someone is going to cause a lot of destruction/pain or any sort of evil/wrong act but they think that their actions are good and just.

Answer (score 2):

deluded [oneself]
"He was deluded that throwing the man in front of the passenger train was going to save his family."

[Psychologically] manipulated [others]
"The German people were manipulated by the Furor into believing the Jews were helping the war effort."

Comment: The usual spelling is Fuehrer.  (or Führer)

Answer (score 0):

There are no polite terms for a person of this sort, I'm afraid. The sentiment is summed up in the pseudo-classical legal term "Fiat justitia ruat caelum," which stands for "Let justice be done though the heavens fall," or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a **necessary evil**.

eg.

> Alcohol checkpoints are a necessary evil. They're invasive and inconvenient, but are the only practical solution to having drunk drivings killing people.

Of course, whether the thing is a necessary evil, a plain evil, or a good thing, is a value judgement by person stating it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of a *sin-eater*, someone who takes the responsibility for sins so that others can live or die absolved of them.